# RecyclerView doesn't remember selection on screen rotation

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

In my `RecyclerView`'s `Adapter` I'm using the following methods to remember the currently selected item and restore it on screen rotation:

```
private final static String SELECTED_ITEM = "MyAdapter.selectedItem";

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    Log.i("onSave","OnSave "+mSelectedItem);
    outState.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM, mSelectedItem);
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    if(savedInstanceState.containsKey(SELECTED_ITEM)){
        Log.i("onRestore","OnRestore " + savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM));
        notifyItemChanged(mSelectedItem);
        mSelectedItem = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM);
        notifyItemChanged(mSelectedItem);
        mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(mSelectedItem);
    }
}
```

And in my `Fragment` containing the `RecyclerView` I'm using:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if(null != mRecyclerView && null != mRecyclerView.getAdapter()){
        ((MyAdapter)mRecyclerView.getAdapter()).onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if(null!=savedInstanceState){
        if(null != mRecyclerView && null != mRecyclerView.getAdapter()){
            ((MyAdapter)mRecyclerView.getAdapter()).onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
}
```

I am seeing the `Log` messages, but the `Adapter` doesn't remember the selection.

Comment: `RecyclerView` has its own [`onRestoreInstanceState`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#L754) ... from Fragment's lifecycle seems like `onActivityCreated` is called before all view's `onRestoreInstanceState` ...

Comment: @Selvin it doesn't store any information about the Adapter and its selected position.

Comment: Go further in debugging, and see why mSelectedItem does not update your UI.

Comment: *it doesn't store any information about the Adapter and its selected position* because it is not a role of Adapter but RecyclerView itself(or its parent) ...

Comment: @selvin could you please explain what I'm doing wrong less cryptically, maybe by writing an actual answer, please?

Comment: @mvai mSelectedItem value is the expected one, but the UI doesn't get updated.

Comment: works like a charm ... https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/9175c8edbdab69a63923

Comment: Thank you @Selvin , I realized that my `Activity` kept creating a new `Fragment` at each rotation because I was not performing any check on `savedInstanceState`, now my code seems to work properly!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Selvin's [code](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/9175c8edbdab69a63923), I soon realized that the problem was that I was recreating the `Fragment` at each screen rotation and the new `Fragment`, of course, had no selection int to restore.

In `onCreate` method of your your root `Activity`, check that you're creating the `Activity` for the first time:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        mContentLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_content_frame);
        if(null==savedInstanceState) {
            mFragment = new MyFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(mContentLayout.getId(), mPlatformsFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Then in your `Fragment`, to save your selected item use:

```
private final static String SELECTED_ITEM = "MyAdapter.mSelectedItem";

//Save your selection
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if(null!=mAdapter){
        outState.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM, mAdapter.mSelectedItem);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

//Restore your selection
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(platformsAdapter.mSelectedItem);
        mAdapter.mSelectedItem = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM, 0);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(platformsAdapter.mSelectedItem);
        mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Align selection to top
                mLayoutManager
                    .scrollToPositionWithOffset(mAdapter.mSelectedItem, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```